# Problem with distribution the velocity to just enabled objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making runner game where character if collide with inactive characters make them active, the problem is if active character collides with bunch of inactive characters who are close enough, speed that inactive character takes from active doesn't distribute to next inactive characters.
Active characters are moved by adding force thats why i can't add force for inactive characters, while they were accelerating active character would go much farther.

Code for enabling characters:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Stickman : MonoBehaviour
{
private Rigidbody _rigidbody;

private void Start()
{
    _rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
{
    CheckColliderObject(collider);
}

private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
{
    CheckColliderObject(other);
}

private void ActivateStickman(Collider collider)
{
    collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Stickman>().enabled = true;
    collider.gameObject.GetComponent<StickmanMover>().enabled = true;
    collider.gameObject.GetComponent<StickmanAnimator>().enabled = true;
    collider.gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<Renderer>().material.color = Color.yellow;
    collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = Vector3.forward * _rigidbody.velocity.magnitude;
}

private void CheckColliderObject(Collider colliderObject)
{
    if (!gameObject.GetComponent<Stickman>().enabled)
    {
        return;
    }
    else if (colliderObject.gameObject.GetComponent<StickmanMover>())
    {
        if (!colliderObject.gameObject.GetComponent<StickmanMover>().enabled)
        {
            ActivateStickman(colliderObject);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by checking if _rigidbody == null and if yes set _rigidbody value:

```
    private void ActivateStickman(Collider collider)
{
    if (_rigidbody == null)
        _rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

    collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Stickman>().enabled = true;
    collider.gameObject.GetComponent<StickmanMover>().enabled = true;
    collider.gameObject.GetComponent<StickmanAnimator>().enabled = true;
    collider.gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<Renderer>().material.color = Color.yellow;
    collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = Vector3.forward * _rigidbody.velocity.magnitude;
}
```